# can we add extra check before download artifact in maven

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, pom.xml

in maven pm dependency i want to download jar from Rest API (Rest API which download jar with some flag that is permission flag)
but before download i want to add some check whether that flag has access or not for the artifact

i have tried

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>build</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <exec executable="bash">
            <arg value="-c" />
            <arg
              value="curl -X GET {Rest api} -o /Users/ids/Documents/jar/xyz-1.1.0.jar" />
          </exec>
        </target>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is working but i am not sure how to check permission flag  before download
permission flag we can check from rest api as well (since data is there in DB) or some custom tag

Comment: Why not just put the artifact in a usual Maven repository (Nexus/Artifactory)?

Comment: since i need to validate flag before download artifact/jar

Comment: I do not understand why you need the whole REST API and the permission flag. Why not upload the artifact to a Nexus/Artifactory and just use it without any REST API in between?

Comment: this is because we want to restrict download from unauthorised user

Comment: You can restrict the download by using accounts in the Nexus or Artifactory server.

Comment: yeah Fabian 
i can use account but here i need artifact label restriction
for example :- some user has artifact permission but some does not

Comment: Please reconsider this approach. Different users can use different accounts on Nexus/Artifactory. Your approach will be peculiar at best, but probably will not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly calling the curl command on your jar use a shell script to do so, Write all your validation logic inside that shell script.
i.e.
 `<arg value="bash myScript.sh param1 param2 ..." />`